# Prevent PHP File from running mulitple time at once

Tags: php, curl

I deduct payment of my users daily by hitting to a url using PHP. There is no specific time when payment should be duducted . So i am not using cron to perform this job . So I call this php file from my browser to deduct payments. But the problem is while entering the url of my php file , browser automatically hit it . and when I hit the url . Sometimes payment is deducted twice . How can i solve this problem . 
I have also used the following code to prevent php file from running if it's instance is running : -

Start of File:-

```
$fp = fopen(__FILE__, "r");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    echo "Got lock!\n";


} else {
    print "Could not get lock!\n";
}
```

End of File:-

```
 flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
```

But it's not working . Please help me to solve this problem .Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to have a database to keep track of which payments from users have executed, and have your script check that first before proceeding to make a new charge.

Comment: Use a caching mechanism (redis/memcached/ Php Object) to store and update sessions and maintain the state of the transactions.

Comment: you need to store somewhere, that this daily tasks is in progress or has already been completed for today. Use an database to track status, you can use Cron to schedule when to execute. I mention database because you can build an bare ui and  interact with the script.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski, It will not work . I'm running select * from BillAsyncLogs where Process_Flag=0 and BillResFinal is not null and source in ('rgrace','fgrace','renewal') . 
This query returns around 1000 results . To process these results it takes around 30 to 35  minutes . After processing each record i update process_flag to 1 . But still i doesn't solve the problem . Suppose i ran first instance of file which returned 1011 results and second instance return 1005 result . now even if first instance has processed a record . Second will again process the record  .

Comment: You will need to made an indepotency system like in some Payments API : https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#idempotent_requests

Comment: It's tough to guess without seeing code. Something like foreach($activecustomers as $ac){if(!isset($process_flag)){... bill them...} else { ... customer already billed today... }

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix , after running file If execute the same file It'll not create any problem because I'm tracking the processed record in database. It creates problem when the same file runs multiple time at same time .

Comment: You can also put a lock on your rows : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 0):

You should simply replace `__FILE__` with something else like `/tmp/my-php-script.lock`, ie:

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/my-php-script.lock", "r");
```